# ListView CheckedTextView

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

In my Android application, my goal I thought would be very simple - To generate a list of installed applications and place a tick box along side each, acting as a 'tick to exclude' list.

To generate the list of installed applications, I'm using the standard Android example code, demonstrated inside a fragment [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock/blob/master/actionbarsherlock-samples/fragments/src/com/actionbarsherlock/sample/fragments/LoaderCustomSupport.java). I won't repost it all to keep this post as concise as possible.

The performance is terrible and my first question on this subject would be requesting **example code that LazyLoads the application icons**. The implementation of LazyLoading icons into a ListView appears to only be a concern when the [images are being downloaded](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview). Since Android does not use this method when generating a list of applications, then I'm wondering if this is therefore overkill?

The problems start when a CheckedTextView is checked and as the views are recycled in the list, [further boxes become ticked down the list](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/SU_N3CstBiM) (out of the initial view) [or they 'forget' they have been ticked](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-developers/zPSHPEHtu94).

To combat this problem, I had to keep a reference to which items were ticked and use the [following code](http://blog.rochdev.com/2011/08/checkedtextview.html) in getView()

```
    // store CheckTextView's
    private static HashMap<Integer, CheckedTextView> mCheckedList = new HashMap<Integer, CheckedTextView>();
    // store state
    private static HashMap<Integer, Boolean> mIsChecked = new HashMap<Integer, Boolean>();

@Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

            View view;

            if (convertView == null) {
                view = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item_icon_text, parent, false);

            } else {
                view = convertView;

            }

            final AppEntry item = getItem(position);

            ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.icon)).setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());

            CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view.findViewById(R.id.text1);
            ctv.setText(item.getLabel());

            // set current state
            if (mIsChecked.get(position) != null) {
                if (mIsChecked.get(position)) {
                    ctv.setChecked(true);
                }
            } else {
                ctv.setChecked(false);
            }

            ctv.setTag(position);
            mCheckedList.put(position, ctv);

            ctv.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {

                    CheckedTextView ct = mCheckedList.get(view.getTag());

                    if (DE.BUG) {
                        MyLog.d("ct text: " + ct.getText().toString());
                    }

                    ct.toggle();

                    mIsChecked.put((Integer) view.getTag(), ct.isChecked());
                }

            });

            return view;

        }
    }
```

That works, but the performance is terrible due to the work done for each view being refreshed/recycled and the OnClickListener placed on each item (more on this below) - Eclipse also tells me there's more something else to change:

> Use new SparseArray(...) instead for better
>   performance

My woes don't end there though.. to help the user get to the application they want quickly, I implemented a filter as follows:

```
@Override public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    // Place an action bar item for searching.
    MenuItem item = menu.add("Search");
    item.setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_search);
    item.setShowAsAction(MenuItem.SHOW_AS_ACTION_IF_ROOM);
    View searchView = SearchViewCompat.newSearchView(getActivity());
    if (searchView != null) {
        SearchViewCompat.setOnQueryTextListener(searchView,
                new OnQueryTextListenerCompat() {
            @Override
            public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                // Called when the action bar search text has changed.  Since this
                // is a simple array adapter, we can just have it do the filtering.
                mCurFilter = !TextUtils.isEmpty(newText) ? newText : null;
                mAdapter.getFilter().filter(mCurFilter);
                return true;
            }
        });
        item.setActionView(searchView);
    }
}
```

I assume when a filter is typed in, the ListView is redrawn and the references to positions become messed up? This results in boxes becoming ticked based on their position on the display.

I had to implement an OnClickListener for each entry above, as I cannot get a reference to the CheckedTextView from onListItemClick. Here are some of my many attempts:

```
@Override
public void onListItemClick(final ListView listView, final View view, final int position, final long id) {

    // View v = (View) listView.getChildAt(position);
    // CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)
    // v.findViewById(R.id.text1);
    // ctv.toggle();

    // RelativeLayout r = (RelativeLayout) view;

    // CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView)
    // r.findViewById(R.id.text1);

    // CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view;

    // ((CheckedTextView)
    // listView.getItemAtPosition(position)).setChecked(!((CheckedTextView)
    // listView
    // .getItemAtPosition(position)).isChecked());

    // CheckedTextView ctv = (CheckedTextView) view.getTag(position);
    // ctv.toggle();
```

As @CommonsWare [replied in this topic](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/android-beginners/c3K5LfpQ7jM/JovqUY_r0HAJ), the CheckedTextView reference to `findViewById(R.id.text1)` is not what I'm after.

EDIT - XML Layout

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingRight="6dip" >

    <CheckedTextView
        android:id="@+id/text1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/icon"
        android:checkMark="?android:attr/listChoiceIndicatorMultiple"
        android:paddingLeft="4dip"
        android:paddingTop="4dip"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:duplicateParentState="true" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/icon"
        android:layout_width="48dip"
        android:layout_height="48dip"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:paddingLeft="2dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I'm about ready to give up and implement my own layout with a separate text view and check box, but I can't help thinking I'll be reinventing the wheel if I do that? Am I making this much harder than it should be!?

In an ideal world:

1. A list of installed applications that LazyLoad the application icons.
2. A reference to the actual CheckedTextView from the onListItemClick.
3. The correct way to store and reference which items have been checked.

I hope someone can help and I thank you in advance.

Comment: `listView.getAdapter().getItemAt(...)` ? Or if you have a reference to the listView's adapter you might have a better time fiddling with this.

Comment: You might have a similar problem to what I had, I had to make a CheckableLinearLayout and let it's children take focus before it. `FOCUS_AFTER_DECENDANTS`.

A new simple XML layout with an adapter will surely take care of this.

Comment: @Shark Thanks - I've added my XML Layout above. Using listView.getAdapter().getItemAt(...) would surely still only get the Parent RelativeLayout? I would then need to get the child CheckedTextView from that? I've looked at other similar options to CheckableLinearLayout, but isn't that reinventing the wheel?